# Клонирование класса GameObject Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу клонировать в скрипте `GameObject` без его появления на сцене(так что `Instantiate` не подойдёт)

```cs
    GameObject prefab = new GameObject();
    GameObject variant = // Волшебное клонирование prefab
    // Тут variant и prefab совершенно идентичны, но ссылаются на разные объекты
```

Comment: а для чего вам клон гейм обджекта которого нету на сцене?

Comment: Что значит "клонировать"?

Comment: @Andrey Я изменяю его в скрипте, а позже возможно делаю Instantiate.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Создать класс GameObject с идентичными prefab значениями.

Comment: не думаю что так выйдет. Именно Instantiate делает клон. В котором уже можно менять все что угодно.

Comment: Игровые объекты всегда привязаны к сцене, так что это так не работает.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Нет, когда я пишу `GameObject prefab = new GameObject();`, я создаю новый экземпляр класса не привязанный ни к какой сцене.

Comment: @Andrey Вариант с изменением после создания на сцене мне не подходит(

Comment: GameObject prefab = new GameObject();
проблема в том что даже это создает объект на сцене. От этого вы не уйдете никак

Comment: "Когда я пишу", ну так пишите, кто против то? :) Еще раз говорю, Игровые объекты всегда привязаны к сцене. C# в Unity работает не всегда так, как указано в спецификации C#.

Comment: Да, действительно, вы совершенно правы. Видимо так сделать не получится(

Comment: Вам никто не мешает инстанциировать префаб и отключить его, потом что-то в нем поменять и наклонировать этот измененный префаб.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Такой способ мне не очень подходит, однако, если он единственный придётся использовать его. Спасибо.

Comment: Чем он вам не подходит? Что мешает удалить в конце этот лишний клон?

Comment: Я буду создавать объекты из префаба несколько раз.

Comment: И что из этого противоречит моему предложению?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это оказалось невозможным, так-как при создании нового GameObject любым способом, Unity добавляет его на сцену автоматически.